# Force IE 9 browser to Emulate IE 8 for child page (Popup)

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-9, x-ua-compatible

I have a SharePoint page renders fine in IE9.
The other page which open is popup (modal dialog in SharePoint) has explictly added following to force to use IE 8 mode:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />`

but the popup page not renders for IE8. If this page is opened seprately it works fine (render in IE8).

Please help!

Thanks,

Amit

Comment: Did you see this http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/03/problems-with-ie8-standards-mode.html